# ¿Por qué me da este error en el bucle for?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy intentando rellenar unas filas con un bucle for en C#. El problema es que me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException   HResult=0x80131502   Mensaje = El
> índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e
> inferior al tamaño de la colección. Nombre del parámetro: index
> Origen = mscorlib   Seguimiento de la pila:    en
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument
> argument, ExceptionResource resource)    en
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)

Pero el código no me debería dar ese error, ya que es el siguiente:

```
select = "SELECT * FROM pesadas where Rechazada= 0 and IDLoteMaquinaProducto=" + dtLotes.Rows[i]["IDLoteMaquinaProducto"] + " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " + muestras.ToString();
                                MessageBox.Show("Valor del lote ID: " +dtLotes.Rows[i]["IDLoteMaquinaProducto"].ToString());
                                dtPesadas = AccesoDatosGenerico.EjecutaQuery(select).Tables[0];

                                if (dtPesadas.Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                List<double> listaPesadasLote = new List<double>();
                                int z = dtPesadas.Rows.Count;

                                    for (int k = 0; k < z; k++)
                                    {
                                    MessageBox.Show("El valor del contador es: " + k);
                                    //Generamos la lista de muestreadas para hallar la desviacion y constante para el informe 3
                                    listaPesadasLote[k] = Double.Parse(dtPesadas.Rows[k]["Peso"].ToString());
                                    }
```

¿Por qué me da ese error? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema se trataba de que es una lista, no un arreglo o array, por lo que esa forma de añadir elementos:

```
 listaPesadasLote[k] = Double.Parse(dtPesadas.Rows[k]["Peso"].ToString());`
```

es errónea. En su lugar, hay que utilizar el método Add.

```
listaPesadasLote.Add(Double.Parse(dtPesadas.Rows[k]["Peso"].ToString());
```

Gracias por vuestros aportes.